# Implementing multiple person relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I've done a facebook like model, but I want the `Personne` to have *more than one link* with another `Personne`.

I have an intermediary table `PersonneRelation` with a custom `save` method. The idea is: when I add a relation to a person, I want to create another relation the other way. The problem is that if I try to save in the `save` method it's a recursive call. So my idea was to create a variable of the class and set it to True only when I want to avoid recursion.

Here's how I did:

```
class Personne(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    relations = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='PersonneRelation',
                                       symmetrical=False)


class PersonneRelation(models.Model):
    is_saving = False
    # TAB_TYPES omitted for brevity
    type_relation = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                                     choices=[(a, b) for a, b in
                                              list(TAB_TYPES.items())],
                                     default=TYPE_FRIEND)
    src = models.ForeignKey('Personne', related_name='src')
    dst = models.ForeignKey('Personne', related_name='dst')
    opposite = models.ForeignKey('PersonneRelation',
                                 null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_saving:
            return super(PersonneRelation, self).save(args, kwargs)
        old = None
        if self.pk and self.opposite:
            old = self.type_relation
        retour = super(PersonneRelation, self).save(args, kwargs)
        if old:
            PersonneRelation.objects.filter(
                src=self.dst, dst=self.src, opposite=self, type_relation=old
            ).update(type_relation=self.type_relation)
        if self.opposite is None:
            self.opposite = PersonneRelation(
                src=self.dst, dst=self.src, opposite=self,
                type_relation=self.type_relation, is_reverse=True)
            self.opposite.save()
            self.is_saving = True
            self.save()
            self.is_saving = False
        return retour
```

My question is: is it safe to do so (using a class variable `is_saving`) (I dont know how Python deals with such variables)? If not, why? I feel like it's not ok, so what are the other possibilities to implement multiple many to many relationship that should behave like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I modified it: I totally removed the `save` method and used the `post_save` message to check:

- if it was created *without* opposite side, I create here with opposite side as the one created (and I can do it here without any problem!) then I update the one created with the "opposite"
- if it wasn't created, this is an update, so just make sure the opposite side is changed as well.

I did this because I'll almost never have to change relationships between people, and when I'll create new ones there wont be any possible race conditions, because of the context where I will create new relationships

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=PersonneRelation)
def signal_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
    created = kwargs['created']
    obj = kwargs['instance']
    if created and not obj.opposite:
        opposite = PersonneRelation(
            src=obj.dst, dst=obj.src, opposite=obj,
            type_relation=obj.type_relation, is_reverse=True)
        opposite.save()
        obj.opposite = opposite
        obj.save()
    elif not created and obj.type_relation != obj.opposite.type_relation:
        obj.opposite.type_relation = obj.type_relation
        obj.opposite.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not safe, because it's not thread-safe. When two simultaneous Django threads will try to save your model, the behaviour can be unpredictable.

If you want to have more reliable locking, take a look, for example, at the [Redis locking](https://github.com/SPSCommerce/redlock-py).

But to be honest, I'd try to implement it using plain reverse relations, maybe incapsulating the complexity into the `ModelManager`.

Answer (score 0):

If I get the idea behind your code, then:

1. Django automatically makes relation available on both ends so you can get from `src` `Personne` to `dst` `Personne` via `PersonneRelation` and reverse `dst` -> `src` in your code. Therefore no need for additional `opposite` field in `PersonneRelation`.
2. If you need to have both symmetrical and asymmetrical realtions, i.e. `src` -> `dst`, but not `dst` -> `src` for particaular record, then I would suggest to add boolean field:

   `class PersonneRelation(models.Model):
       symmetrical = models.BooleanField(default=False)`

this way you can check if `symmetrical` is `True` when accessing relation in your code to identify if it's `scr` -> `dst` only or both `src` -> `dst` and `dst` -> `src`. In facebook terms: if `symmetrical` is `False` you get `src` is subscriber of `dst`, if it's `True` you get mutual friendship between `src` and `dst`. You might want to define custom manager to incapsulate this behavior, though it's more advanced topic.

3. If you need to check if the model instance is being saved or updated, there's no need in `is_saving` boolean field. Since you're using automatic primary key field, you can just check if `pk` on model instance is `None`.  In Django before the model instance is first time saved to DB ('created') `pk` is `None`, when the instance is 'updated' (it has been read from DB before and is being saved now with some field values changed) it's `pk` is set to `pk` value from `DB`. This is the way Django ORM decides if it should update or create new record.
4. In general when redefining `Save` method on a model, or when using signals like `pre_save`/`post_save` take into consideration, that those functions you define on them might not be called by Django in some circumstances, i.e. when the model is updated in bulk. See Django docs for more info.

Comment: I need kinddof "duplicate" record with reverse src - dst for speed reasons.

Comment: Why you expect speed increase with additional field? Which probably in some uses will even add extra `join` to DB request. May be try adding indexes first. Anyway, it's best not to assume, but benchmark first with such kind of 'optimizations'.

Comment: If I want to select **all** friends of one guy, I need to do a join on `WHERE src=guy`, and if I follow your suggestion, I would need to do *as well* a join on `WHERE dst=guy`. because the guy could be either src or dst, whereas with my solution I only have to do one join on `WHERE src=guy`. So my wild guess is that one join no 4M rows is faster than two joins on two different column on 2M rows. Do you think I'm wrong?

Comment: I don't think that you're wrong. :) I think it's best to benchmark and see the result, if it'll be a bottleneck. Although, I guess you could also use `UNION`, something like: `SELECT F.friend_id FROM (SELECT dst AS friend_id FROM PersonneRelation WHERE src=person_id AND symmetrical=true UNION SELECT src AS friend_id FROM PersonneRelation WHERE dst=person_id AND symmetrical=true) as F`. For `Personne` with `person_id` this should grant all his friend's ids as `F.friend_id` which you can use in single join on `Personne` or in other ways.